# How to pass unsafe HttpClient to Volley request in Android

Tags: android, retrofit, android-volley, retrofit2, httpclient

I'm working with Android application development and my application contains Volley library to make API calls, but I'm facing challenges with SSL:self signed certificate problem with url which I used in code. but it is working in another project with Retrofit library by passing "unsafe HttpClient", So please let me know how can I fix this issue or how can I pass "unsafe HttpClient" to Volley to make API calls.

Comment: Hello @Suresh . I am assuming that your app is working fine and you are getting a warning in your Logcat. Or is your application not working at all?

Comment: my application is not working at all, here is the error I'm getting. 

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found and it is working for me, Please let me know anything wrong here. Here is the code need to add to make a call.

```
final String url = "YOUR URL";
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, getHttpStack(url));
    // prepare the Request
    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // display response
                    Log.e("test", "Response" + response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("test", "Error.Response: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );

    queue.add(getRequest);
```

Here is the methods, need to add in code.

```
private HurlStack getHttpStack(String urlToValidate) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(urlToValidate);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String baseUrl = url.getAuthority();
    return new HurlStack() {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection createConnection(final java.net.URL url)
                throws IOException {
            HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) super
                    .createConnection(url);
            try {
                httpsURLConnection
                        .setSSLSocketFactory(handleSSLHandshake(httpsURLConnection));
                httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        //return true;
                        HostnameVerifier hv =
                                HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
                        return hv.verify(baseUrl, session);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return httpsURLConnection;
        }
    };
}

@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static SSLSocketFactory handleSSLHandshake(HttpsURLConnection connection) {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                Log.e("test", "RETURN TRUE: ");
                return true;
            }
        });
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory newFactory = sc.getSocketFactory();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(newFactory);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }

    return connection.getSSLSocketFactory();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to you AndoidManifest.xml in the application tag :-

```
 <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```